# data not received from database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, email, error-handling

I try to mail my customers through CodeIgniter, its like when I register the appointment its send the email by finding customer email in customer table & other stuff from other table & send the email for confirmation.

this is my App_model.php

```
  public function send_mail()
     {

       $query=$this->db
       ->select('*, employee.name_emp as emp_name, customer.name as 
        cust_name, servicetype.name_set as s_name, serviceplan.price as 
         p_rice')
       ->from('appointment')

         ->join( 'customer', 'customer.id= appointment.name_app')
         ->join( 'servicetype', 'servicetype.id_set= appointment.sertype')
         ->join( 'employee', 'employee.id_emp= appointment.emp')
       //  ->join('serviceplan', 'serviceplan.price=appointment.price_app')
       ->get();



    return $query->result();
     }
```

this is my App_controller

```
       function sendmail($appointment_id){
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
            'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
        );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        // Set to, from, message, etc.
        $this->load->model('App_model');
        $appointment=$this->App_model->send_mail($appointment_id);
       // print_r($appointment);
        //exit();

       $message=Array(
           $message=Array(
      'Name'=>$appointment[0]->cust_name,
     'Service Type'=>$appointment[0]->s_name,
    // 'Service Plan'=>$appointment->p_rice,
     'Employee'=>$appointment[0]->emp_name,
      'Date'=>$appointment[0]->date,
     'Time'=>$appointment[0]->time

    );
          $this->email->from('xxx', 'xxx');
               $this->email->to('xxx');

               $this->email->subject('Confirmation of Your Appointment');
               $this->email->message($message);

        $result = $this->email->send();
         }
```

I check by `print_r($appoinment)` & its shows all data, but when I run the whole program it does not show any error & still mail is not working

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/App_controller.php

Thank you for helping

Comment: just print $query I think your query will not work.

Comment: I'm assuming `send_mail()` should be `send_mail($appointment_id)` otherwise how are you getting `$appointment_id` in the function (typo)? Further I tend to agree with the others, you are getting no rows. Either your query is not doing what you think it is doing or `$appointment_id` doesn't relate to anything ... or your typo wasn't actually a typo in which case I'm surprised you aren't getting errors...

Comment: I remove $appointment_id from model now its working but still not able send data through mail

Comment: can you add the print_r result also and for smtp send mail you need the email id and password to then only mail is going to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a variable from controller to model here

```
$appointment=$this->App_model->send_mail($appointment_id);
```

But in model your are not receiving the any variable.

```
public function send_mail()
```

Change it to

```
public function send_mail($appointment_id)
```

You need to use passed $appointment_id in where condition,if not it return all the rows in table.